# Teradata - joining query for single partition

Tags: teradata

I need to run a query which joins 5 large table on user_id and filter it on proc_date.

I have planed to do partition on proc_date and partition(5 range partition) on user_id to increase query performance. I keep primary index as well on proc_date and user_id.

"But how can I run the query for just one partition of the user_id at a time? I want to restrict the query to join first partition(on User_id) of every table"

Reason behind this is, once I complete the query for first partition, I can send the output data for next process. While next process is running i can run the query for 2nd partition.

Could anyone please give me some solution to achieve this.

Comment: Can you share the table definitions or at a minimum the definition of the tables primary indexes and partitioning schemes? If you want partition elimination you have to qualify on a partitioning column. Tables that share a primary index will perform AMP local joins.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the suggestion. I am new teradata.  I need to give high level design as solution.  I do not want to join entire contents of tables at single time. I want to join a small set of table with corresponding small set of other table, so that I will have part of output data in very short period. I know how to do in Hive, but I am not sure in teradata.

Comment: I can create primary index on proc_date or user_id.